# Using .env.local file. Getting process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV is undefined on client

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, vercel

I'm using Next.js with Vercel. This is my `.env.local` file:

```
# Created by Vercel CLI
VERCEL="1"
VERCEL_ENV="development"
VERCEL_URL=""
VERCEL_GIT_PROVIDER=""
VERCEL_GIT_REPO_SLUG=""
VERCEL_GIT_REPO_OWNER=""
VERCEL_GIT_REPO_ID=""
VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF=""
VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_SHA=""
VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE=""
VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_LOGIN=""
VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME=""
```

I have a component that is trying to access: `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV` to make sure it is on `development` environment.

This is what I'm getting when running `npm run dev`.

Logs from the server:

[image]

The logs above make perfect sense. Since it's running on the local server to render the pages.

But when my client code tries to do the same, I'm getting:

[image]

This is how I'm trying to acess it:

```
console.log(`process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV: ${JSON.stringify(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV)}`);
console.log(`process.env.VERCEL_ENV: ${JSON.stringify(process.env.VERCEL_ENV)}`);
```

On client, the `VERCEL_ENV` should be undefined, but `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV` should be `development`, right?

What could be happening?

---

**UPDATE**

I even tried to add `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV="development"` to the `.env.local` file. But so far, the result is the same.

Comment: I just tested its working on my end. Have you restarted the local dev after changing the .env.local file.? if you dont restart it will show undefined.

Comment: @DipankarMaikap But do you have to add the `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV` or is it working just with `VERCEL_ENV` ? The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) says you should add it: ***By default all environment variables loaded through .env.local are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser. In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_. For example:*** Did you do that?

Comment: You have to add ```NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV``` in order to access it from browser.

Comment: @DipankarMaikap Thanks. It's working now. I had tried that before but for some intermitent weird local issue it didn't work initially. Feel free to write an answer if you'd like.

Comment: anything you add ```NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV``` like this will be available in the browser if you only want something in server just use ```VERCEL_ENV```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV="development"
```

You will have access to this everywhere (in the browser and Server).

```
VERCEL_ENV="development"
```

You only have access to this in the server, in the browser it will show undefined.

Please note after you add or make any changes in the `.env.local` file you have to restart your server otherwise it will show `undefined` if you `console.log` the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Automatically expose System Environment Variables is checked in your Project Settings.

[System Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ6pF.png)

More info [in docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#system-environment-variables)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32991508)